# rpy2 rsqlite Error in loadNamespace(name)

Tags: python, r, rpy2, rsqlite

I have correctly installed rpy2 in my windows pc and it seems working correctly.
Now I would like to "translate" a R routine in rpy2 but when I try to load specific R libraries I got an error just with the loading of the RSQLite library. This is the error message:

```
rsqlite=importr('RSQLite','C:/Users/flc/Documents/R/win-library/3.0')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\packages.py", line 306, in importr
    env = _get_namespace(rname)
RRuntimeError: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'RSQLite'
```

It seems a specific issue regarding such a library and rpy2 since I succeed loading other libraries.
Could you help me please?
Thank you

Comment: Maybe you should install it before loading ?

Comment: Sorry, I did not specify that RSQLite results correctly installed within R where it works correctly. Moreover I verified that RSQLite is installed in the directory specified in the importr calling. Again it seems something related to the specific library since I succeed with other libraries and same conditions.

Comment: Work fine for me, Under ubuntu. No reason that you have only problem with RSQLite.

Comment: I found the solution just first loading the DBI library. So it seems that rpy2 doesn't manage R packages dependencies automatically as R does. Thank you.